# Auditbeat not picking up authentication events in CentOs 7

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastic-beats

I am trying to ship the authentication related of my CentOS 7 to Elasticsearch. Strangely I am not getting any authentication events.

When I ran the **debug command** `auditbeat -c auditbeat.conf -d -e "*"` , I found something like below:

```
 {
      "@timestamp": "2019-01-15T11:54:37.246Z",
      "@metadata": {
        "beat": "auditbeat",
        "type": "doc",
        "version": "6.4.0"
      },
      "error": {
        "message": "failed to set audit PID. An audit process is already running (PID 68504)"
      },
      "beat": {
        "name": "env-cs-westus-devtest-66-csos-logs-es-master-0",
        "hostname": "env-cs-westus-devtest-66-csos-logs-es-master-0",
        "version": "6.4.0"
      },
      "host": {
        "name": "env-cs-westus-devtest-66-csos-logs-es-master-0"
      },
      "event": {
        "module": "auditd"
      }
    }
```

**Also there was an error line like below:**

```
Failure receiving audit events {"error": "failed to set audit PID. An audit process is already running (PID 68504)"}
```

**Machine details**

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

**Audibeat Configuration File**

```
#================================ General ======================================
fields_under_root: False
queue:
  mem:
    events: 4096
    flush:
      min_events: 2048
      timeout: 1s
max_procs: 1
max_start_delay: 10s
#================================= Paths ======================================
path:
  home: "/usr/share/auditbeat"
  config: "/etc/auditbeat"
  data: "/var/lib/auditbeat"
  logs: "/var/log/auditbeat/auditbeat.log"
#============================  Config Reloading ================================
config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/conf.d/*.yml
    reload:
      period: 10s
      enabled: False
#==========================  Modules configuration =============================
auditbeat.modules:
#----------------------------- Auditd module -----------------------------------
- module: auditd
  resolve_ids: True
  failure_mode: silent
  backlog_limit: 8196
  rate_limit: 0
  include_raw_message: True
  include_warnings: True
  audit_rules: |
    -w /etc/group -p wa -k identity
    -w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity
    -w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity
    -w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity
    -w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open,creat,truncate,ftruncate,openat,open_by_handle_at -F exit=-EACCES -k access
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open,creat,truncate,ftruncate,openat,open_by_handle_at -F exit=-EPERM -k access
    -a always,exit -F dir=/home -F uid=0 -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -C auid!=obj_uid -F key=power-abuse
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/su -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/su -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setresuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/sudo -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setresuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/sudo -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -F key=elevated-privs
#----------------------------- File Integrity module -----------------------------------
- module: file_integrity
  paths:
    - /bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /sbin
    - /usr/sbin
    - /etc
    - /home/jenkins
  exclude_files:
    - (?i)\.sw[nop]$
    - ~$
    - /\.git($|/)
  scan_at_start: True
  scan_rate_per_sec: 50 MiB
  max_file_size: 100 MiB
  hash_types: [sha1]
  recursive: False
#================================ Outputs ======================================
#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output -------------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  enabled: True
  hosts:
    - x.x.x:9200
  compression_level: 0
  protocol: "http"
  worker: 1
  bulk_max_size: 50
  timeout: 90
#================================ Logging ======================================
logging:
  level: "info"
  selectors: ["*"]
  to_syslog: False
  to_eventlog: False
  metrics:
    enabled: True
    period: 30s
  to_files: True
  files:
    path: /var/log/auditbeat
    name: "auditbeat"
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760
    keepfiles: 7
    permissions: 0600
  json: False
```

**Version of Auditbeat**
auditbeat version 6.4.0 (amd64), libbeat 6.4.0

Have anyone faced a similar issue and got a resolution?.

**Note:** this configuration for auditbeat successfully captures authentication events for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

So I posted the same in the Elastic beats forum and got a solution. You can find the same [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/auditbeat-not-picking-up-authentication-events-in-centos-7/164304/4)

As per their suggestion, turning off the auditd service would allow Audit events to be captured by Audibeat. I tried the same and it worked for me. But I am not sure of the implications of turning the auditd off. So I might switch to a Filebeat based solution.